# HttParty: set default header for all requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-headers, default-value

In some HTTP Clients theres one way to do something like:

```rb
HttpClient.default_headers = { "my-header": "a-value" }
```

And then every request done with that client will include those headers.

Is there any way to do this with [jnunemaker/httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to make this work running without having to use class methods:

```rb
HTTParty::Basement.headers 'my-header' => 'a value'
```

You could use it with hooks from rails like this:

```rb
require "httparty"

module DefaultHeadersForHttparty
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :apply_http_party_headers

    private

    def apply_http_party_headers
      HTTParty::Basement.headers 'my-header' => 'a value'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There is!

```rb
class MyIntegrationClass
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://somedomain.com/api'
  headers 'my-header' => 'a-value'

  def some_method
    response = get('/endpoint')
    JSON.parse(response.to_s, symbolize_names: true)
  end
end
```

The get request will have the `my-header` header set.

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if Im wrong, you are creating a custom Http Client that all the code must use? what happens if the request is done in another class?